# Renaming multiple file names at the same time; keep file type the same

Tags: renaming

I'm using the terminal on a Mac. I am using bash shell.

I have the following three files:

1. 104_S75_R1_001_fastqc.html
2. 104_S75_R1_001_fastqc.zip
3. 104_S75_R1_001.fastq.gz

I would like to replace any occurrence of '104_S75_R1_001' with 'SIL36' so that I end up with the following:

1. SIL36_fastqc.html
2. SIL36_fastqc.zip
3. SIL36.fastq.gz

I'm not even sure which search terms I need to figure this out (regular expressions?). Can I simply use mv or do I need something more complicated, like a loop?

I believe that I have the rename command available.

Comment: What OS are you using? Are you trying to do this with bash?

Comment: In what language are you trying to do that and on what OS?

Comment: My apologizes for leaving this out. I'm working in the terminal on a Mac. Yes, I am trying to do this with bash.